# Tableau data Extract Fails with Large Data source

Tags: amazon-redshift, tableau-api

I am using `Tableau Desktop 8.2` with connection to `Amazon Redshift` creating an extract and publishing data source to tableau server is my task, but recently i'm encountering some issue like

`"Data connection Lost Unable to create an Extract"`

`"Communication error while getting a tuple;
Error fetching next row
Unable to create extract"`

We increased the number of cursors in Amazon Redshift

My concern is when say like 16 Million records are to be extracted and extraction goes till 8 Million and the above error occurs is it possible to get the Extract for last 8 Million Atleast ?

Every thing get rolled back after a Failure / error is it possible to prevent this 
what are my options?

Comment: Not sure how your db is structured, nor how the connection with Amazon Redshift is made, but there should be a possibility to extract a limited number of rows and then refresh incrementally.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the data extract API and have more control over the connection and error handling, at the cost of writing a modest C, Python or Java program